# Renaming a file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to rename a file named `output.txt` with timestamp in python but i am getting **Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python27/rename.py", line 10, in <module>
    os.rename('output.txt', newfile)
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

My code is below :

```
import datetime
import os

dt = str(datetime.datetime.now())
newtime =  ".".join(dt[0:19].split())
newfile = 'output'+newtime+'.txt'

os.rename('output.txt', newfile)
```

Comment: Colon (:) is not allowed in file name in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string dt may has colons: `dt = str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(':', '_')`

EDIT: multple dots in names still work on windows and most other filesystems!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I was not aware of it :)

Answer (score 0):

The new file name is 'output2017-02-25.10:57:32.txt' which is an invalid file name for windows (since it contains ':' and '.')

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I was not aware of it